# Trying to get property of non-object - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to get the `teacher_id` that is corresponding to the teacher's first and last name that the user has entered, but when I try to get the `teacher_id` it outputs `Trying to get property of non-object`. Does anyone have any ideas?

PHP

```
<?php

// PROCESSES STUDENT INFO

// get connect page
require '../../connect.php';

// get input info
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$teacher_first_name = $_POST['teacher_first_name'];
$teacher_last_name = $_POST['teacher_last_name'];

// check if input is not empy
if(!empty($student_id) && !empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($teacher_first_name) && !empty($teacher_last_name)) {

    // check if numeric inputs have a number
    if(is_numeric($student_id)) {
        $teacher_check = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT teacher_id FROM teachers WHERE first_name='$teacher_first_name' AND last_name='$teacher_last_name'");

        // check if teacher exists
        if($teacher_check) {
            $row = $teacher_check->fetch_object();

            $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO students (student_id, first_name, last_name, teacher_id) VALUES ($student_id, '$first_name','$last_name', $row->teacher_id)");

            if($result) {
                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");
            } else {
                echo mysqli_error($link);
                // header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Sorry we ran into an error");
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Teacher Does Not Exist");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Please add a number for Student ID");
    }

} else if (empty($student_id) || empty($first_name) || empty($last_name)) {
    header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Please add you're input values");
}
```

?>

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line, you are checking whether the query is ok but you have not checked whether it has any results.

```
if($teacher_check) {
        $row = $teacher_check->fetch_object();
```

to (this line checks whether you have any result data if you have result data you have it $row otherwise null)

```
if($row = $teacher_check->fetch_object()){
```